# Bootstrap forms: it doesn't retrive POST data. With GET it does

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, post, get

Implementing forms with bootstrap's classes, in a first page I wrote this code

```
<form action="dologin.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
<input type="image" src="img/login.png" alt="Login">
</form>
```

and in *dologin.php* I tried to retrive the data in this way

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
echo $email;
```

It doesn't work, it doesn't print anything.

But if I use the get method, in first page:

```
<form action="dologin.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
<input type="image" src="img/login.png" alt="Login">
</form>
```

In *dologin.php*

```
$email = $_GET['email'];
echo $email;
```

It works printing what was input in the form.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it has something to do with the "image" input.
have you considered using a button element instead?

```
<button type="submit" name="someName" value="someValue"><img src="someImage.png" alt="SomeAlternateText"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
<form action="dologin.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="image" src="img/login.png" type="submit" alt="Login">
</form>
```

And in dologin.php :

```
email = $_POST['email'];
echo $email;
```

Comment: Is your comment inclomplete, isn't it?

Comment: Type "image" is already submit-type. Also the second `type` attribute will just overwrite the first.